# Check box read only in a gridview asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I have a gridview with a checkbox field . I need to make the checkbox read only

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdExam" 
              CssClass="grid" 
              runat="server" 
              AutoGenerateColumns="false"  
              DataKeyNames="Id">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" 
                        HeaderText="ID" 
                        SortExpression="ID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" 
                        HeaderText="Name" 
                        SortExpression="Name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Type_Id" 
                        HeaderText="Type" 
                        SortExpression="Type" />
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelect" 
                              runat="server" 
                              Checked='<%# Eval("Enabled")%>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

There  is no server side property to make the Checkbox readonly. IS there any server side code that i can use to make the checkbox read only.

Answer (score 1):

You can't set it to readonly for checkbox but you can use alternate way...

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="xxx" runat="server" onclick="return false" />
```

Anyway why you didn't use Enabled="false" ?
If you don't let the user to check.... just use Enabled="false"

Comment: `Enabled=False` is solution. Why unnecessary adding that `onclick`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer . The issue with Enable is false it greys the control out . I don't want to grey the control.

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chkReadOnly" Checked="true" OnClick="return false;" />
```